# Unable to catch and log the Error response from an axios request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, axios

I am having a axios request in my react application, for which I am following the **[axios npm docs.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)**

This is my axios request

```
 axios.post(helper.getLoginApi(), data)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);

            this.props.history.push(from.pathname)
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

I am able to successfully log the data on a successful request. However When I intentionally produce an error and try to console.log it, I don't get the result logged instead, I just see

> POST http://localhost:3000/login 401 (Unauthorized) 
>   :3000/login:1
>   Error: Request failed with status code 401 
>   login.js:66
>
> at createError (createError.js:16)
>
> at settle (settle.js:18)
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)

However when I go to Network Tab in Chrome Console, I can see the below response returned.

[image]

Thanks for help in advance .

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your axios into a `try {} catch(e) {}` statement? Have you tried checking the `response.status` inside `then`? Just some ideas - I don't know why it won't work

Comment: @lumio, as I said, in .then , I am able to successfully log `response.data` but not in the `.catch` block

Comment: Even though I use axios by myself I'm not sure if axios always fails when status isn't `2xx`. Have you tried throwing an error inside `then` when `response.status` is not 200?

Comment: I haven't tried that, I will do that once I try the answer posted by @ShubhamKhatri and if it doesn't work

Answer (score 34):

From the **[Github Docs](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors)**. The response of an axios request looks like

```
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance the browser
  request: {}
}
```

So essentially  `catch(error => )` is actually just `catch(response => )`

and so you can log `error.response.data`  and you should be able to see your response message.

> When you log `console.log(error)`, what you see is the `string`
>   returned by the `toString` method on the `error` object.

According to the error handling section on the same docs, you can have the catch the error response like

```
axios.post(helper.getLoginApi(), data)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);

            this.props.history.push(from.pathname)
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            if (error.response) {
              // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
              // that falls out of the range of 2xx
              console.log(error.response.data);
              console.log(error.response.status);
              console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
              // The request was made but no response was received
              // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
              // http.ClientRequest in node.js
              console.log(error.request);
            } else {
              // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
              console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
        })
```