# React: Axios Network Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This is my first time using axios and I have encountered an error.

```
  axios.get(
    `http://someurl.com/page1?param1=1&param2=${param2_id}`
  )
  .then(function(response) {
    alert();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

With the right url and parameters, when I check network requests I indeed get the right answer from my server, but when I open console I see that it didn't call the callback, but instead it caught an error.

> Error: Network Error
>   Stack trace:
>   createError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2188:15
>   handleError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1717:14

Comment: You might be able to figure out more about this using `console.log(error.response.data)`.

Comment: See this answer, it will help you knowing what the error is exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806333/unable-to-catch-and-log-the-error-response-from-an-axios-request/44806462#44806462

Comment: @FaustoNA error.response is undefined

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri apparently CORS is the problem

Comment: Great you were able to figure it out. But do handle errors with axios as mentioned in the link I posted

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I still didn't manage to make it work. I get status: 0. 

Thanks for the advice for error handling.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## If Creating an API Using NodeJS

---

Your Express app needs to use CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). Add the following to your server file:

```js
// This should already be declared in your API file
var app = express();

// ADD THIS
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

For fuller understanding of CORS, please read the [Mozilla Documentation on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: I am not using Express. I am using Axios in ReactJS app. What can I do to use CORS in axios?

Comment: One important point is to add the cors middleware before the code that you handle the request

Comment: THANKS!, Life saving. I was trying to run an angular app that talked to node from my phone, and it did not worked. Even when it worked from my computer. If node cannot find CORS "module not found", just run npm install cors.

Comment: this answer apply also for NestJS, I got the same error in the client side, and had to add `{ cors: true }` to `NestFactory.create`. - ,,,,,
`app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });  `

Comment: I am using django. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 17):

my problem was about the url I was requesting to. I hadn't inserted `http://` at the beginning of my url. I mean I was requesting to a url like `92.920.920.920/api/Token` instead of `http://92.920.920.920/api/Token`. adding `http://` solved my problem.

Comment: I am using that, I even upload my nodejs app to heroku

Answer (score 14):

It happens when you work on localhost and forgot to add  **http://**

Wrong Usage

```
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: apiKey,
  };
  const url = "localhost:5000/api/expenses/get-expenses";

  axios.get(url, { headers });

  // NETWORK ERROR
```

The correct one is

```
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: apiKey,
  };
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/expenses/get-expenses";

  axios.get(url, { headers });

  // WORKS FINE IF YOU HANDLED CORS CORRECTLY IN THE SERVER SIDE
```

Comment: Forgetting the port made it not work for me, and this help trigger the thought, thanks!

Comment: Also, when you are on localhost and use `https`

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @jacobhobson answer, I had also used some parameters to made it work.

```
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having same issue on production on digital ocean droplet. I was using **axios** in **ReactJS** to call **Node.js** API.

Although I included cors

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

But I still had to add

```
res.header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" );
```

before calling out my controller. And it worked for me. There I realized that cors is not working properly. So I uninstalled and installed them again and It Works!

Complete code is here.

So either you use

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-access-token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

or use

```
app.use(cors());
```

It's the same.

Comment: and where I should include cors 
```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
``` ?

Comment: You can use it before calling your routes in server.js or if you are using some middleware then you can put these lines there. P.S. I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: I have use `app.use(cors());` though it is showing network error. But not every time I am receiving this error. I am calling an API for the video uploading. After several times calling it is throwing me the network error.

Comment: @JaynaTanawala Have you installed cors? Try running "npm install cors --save"

Comment: yes. Have installed it.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I used "**https**" instead of "**http**", check that too.

Comment: for example, you should use  `https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets` Not `api.coincap.io/v2/assets`  in Axios URL

Comment: That exact my issue, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

I received a network error with axios 0.27.2 when I was trying to upload an image to our server. After I set headers like below no error is received.

```
headers:{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, /","Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
```

and you need to check with your api request's body type in your collection like if it's form-data or x-wwww-form-urlencoded or ..etc.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to let you know that after searching for a solution for two days, I was able to solve my error.
Since the proxy was the source of the issue, I must configure a proxy in the package.json file, and I have to follow these instructions in the function that uses Axios:

```
try { await axios.post("user/login", formData).then((res) => { console.log(res.data); }); } catch (error) { console.log(error.response.data.message); }
```

and in package.json file need to add a proxy:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:6000",
```

for better understand check this documentation: [enter link description here](https://www.jamesqquick.com/blog/configure-proxy-in-react/)

Comment: where should I add it? in the client's package.json or the server's package.json?

Comment: @GouravSanyal This works for me by adding the proxy on client's package.json

Comment: But I am confused that what happens when I will host my web application I will have to change it when I host my web application?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the same port number in `cors({ origin : [ "http://localhost:3001"]})` and the `.env` file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running `react native` in `development` while using `real device` connected via USB(*and the API server is being accessed via development machine IP*), ensure the **development machine** and the **device** are both connected to the **same network**

Answer (score 2):

Even though I had CORS in my project already, I encountered an error with the "network error" flag in axios because I was passing custom headers into axios before the post data.

The post data in axios should always be the second argument, then the custom headers last.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue by adding this header.

```
var data = new FormData();
              data.append('request', 'CompaniesData');
           var config = {
                 method: 'post',
                 url: baseUrl, headers:{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, /","Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
                    data : data
                  };
            
                 axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. change the `port` number of your node server.
   It took more than 3 hours to solve this error. Solution ended with changing port numer which was initially set to 6000, later set to 3001. Then it worked. My server localhost base url was:

   `"http://localhost:6000/data"`

   I changed port number in `app.listen()` on server and from frontend I call that `GET` route in `async` function as
   `await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/data')`.
   It is working fine now.
2. If you face the address issue: `address already in use :::#port`

   Then on command prompt: `killall -9 node`

Comment: you saved mine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of restrict-origin-when-cross-origin policy.Browser sends a pre-flight request to know whom the API server wants to share the resources.
So you have to set origin there in API server and send some status.After that the browser allow to send the request to the  API server.

Here is the code.I am running front-end on localhost:8000 and api server is running on port 6000.

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.options("*", cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:8000', optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));

app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:8000", optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));
```

I have set origin as my front-end url, If You  set it to true , then it will allow only port 8000 to access rosource, and  front-end running on port 8000 can  not access this resource. Use this middleware before route in api server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using Hapi.js as the backend, so all I had to do is set the cors value to true as in the code below;

```
const server = Hapi.server({
       port: 4000,
       host: 'localhost',
       state: {
           strictHeader: false
       },
       routes: {
           cors: true
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using http:// requests there is a chance to occur this error.

To avoid the u can use https:// base url
or u can enable android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest
[question]: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

recommended using https: //yoururl/api not http: // your url

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was assigning string to url

like :
{url : 'link' } --> this is wrong

```
   {url : link } --> this is correct
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm using axios in react-native as android and .net as backend, i have same issue but i can't solve the problem. I think it is security problem when i type the url in chrome it warns me about that in emulator.

```
axios("http://10.0.2.2:5001/api/Users/getall")
  .then((result) => setUsers(result.data.data))
  .then((json) => {
    return json.data;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  })
  .then((response) => response.parse());
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using localhost api so connected with the same wifi and replace localhost to IP then everything is fine......