# Fetching data using API in react.js

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux, axios

I am trying to fetch data using API in react.js. My code is like below

```
import Axios from 'axios';

export const getCountry = () => dispatch => {
  return Axios.get('http://treeoverflow.com/api/country/listing/true/111111111111222222222222333333333333444444444444', { crossdomain: true })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    var countryData = response.data;
    dispatch({
      type: 'getCountries',
      payload: countryData
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('hello');
    dispatch({
      type: 'getCountryError',
      payload: error
    });
  });
};

export default { getCountry };
```

I getting below view in `Network` tab.

[image]

But I am not getting result. Is there any issue in this URL 'http://treeoverflow.com/api/country/listing/true/111111111111222222222222333333333333444444444444'  ?

Comment: what is the error coming?

Comment: did you try set header for your request? as second param try set {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Thanks for your reply. I am getting result of `console.log('hello');`.

Comment: @EhsanSadeghi, I am getting same output using your solution. Thanks.

Comment: what is value of error in catch?

Comment: tried with different link and is working well

Comment: @eramit2010, I am getting this error `Error: "Network Error"
    createError createError.js:17
    handleError xhr.js:80`

Comment: @emaan14, is there any issue with that URL ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data) it may helps

Comment: @SrikanthGowda, Could you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Have you tried to check the network tab in your browser to see if any http error codes are popping up ?

Comment: @Muljayan, I am getting this error `Error: "Network Error" createError createError.js:17 handleError xhr.js:80`.Thanks

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but I've searched and found this, it may help you,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980173/react-axios-network-error

Comment: check networks in your browser. not the console.

Comment: @abuabu your code is okay , actually problem with your requested api url.
they blocked sever side execution .... discuss with them.

Comment: @Muljayan, How to check networks in browser ?

Comment: right click, inspect element and there you have a tab called network