# Axios fails with unclear erros while browser can request API

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I want to make simple get request to my API deployed to Heroku. Here is how:

```
axios.get(my_url_here).then(res => this.topics = res.data).catch(e => {
         print(JSON.stringify(e)); 
     });
```

But, only catch works and it prints following:

```
{"message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Network Error\n at createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:83:14)","config":{"url":"my_url_here","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1}}
```

That error does not say anything. I couldn't find good materials about it, but some of them tells that it is a problem related to cors. I don't have any code related to `Allow-origin` stuff on my API, but how the web browser successfully makes requests? And why axios fails and cannot make that requests? I tried to use `cors` library on my server-side but when I deployed code to Heroku, it just stopped working. What can be the reason for above error and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried pinging `my_url_here` and see if your server is alive and returns packets?

Comment: It is absolutely alive. Because, I can make get requests via browser or Postman. It works. I don't know why it fails with axios.

Comment: It must be a CORS issue. Postman doesn't do the preflight request that's why you get the response. Are you using express for your server? can you put your code here?

Comment: Yes, I use express. It is simple get request. Any cors stuff not configured. Can you send some link about how to configured it properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Axios Network Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980173/react-axios-network-error)