# Axios Returing "AxiosError" While Making A Get Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

```
const getProducts = async ()=>{
        try {
          const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products")
          console.log(res)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
```

this is my code in console its showing "AxiosError
code: "ERR_NETWORK" " etc....

Comment: ERR_NETWORK means it is not able to connect to your server. Kindly make sure your local server is running and also check if the port is correct.

Comment: @Yehya I rechecked server is live and port number is same but still returning "ERR_NETWORK"

Comment: did you try making the Get request to server using Postman? what does it return?

Comment: @Yehya yeah I tried its working. Its returning the data

Comment: This stackoverflow comment might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980173/react-axios-network-error#comment78919641_45980173

If you try doing a `console.log(error.response.data)` and posting the full error message output someone will be able to catch it.

Comment: @AlexMapley I tried its showing data : `undefined`  btw I am using it with react