# I don't know exactly if it's a bug from the API or axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, axios, postman

I had a problem is that when I type **`console.log(response.data)` **It should show me an object Containing many arrays, but its place shows me an error: **Uncaught (in promise) =>** I get this error in the console

Knowing that there is no error in my API because when I try it in postman it brings the correct parameters.

this is my code :

```
const baseUrl = "https://....";

function getStandings() {
  const url = `${baseUrl}/standings`

  axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      "X-Auth-Token": `${token}`
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  });

}

getStandings();
```

**⚠ note** : `token` and `baseUrl` they correct.

It goes in the error and I log it to the console. This is what I get::

`message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …`

Comment: Please submit code as text not as an image

Comment: Do you use protocol (`http://` or `https://`) in your base url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Axios Network Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980173/react-axios-network-error)

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You never catched the error in this promise using `.catch(error)`. Check your URL and headers for typos.

Comment: @node_modules I used it but still not working.

Comment: and i use `https://`

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, only the problem was with **`CORS`** I had to enter from a browser that does not support it to show me the result of the API.

This site helped me a lot => [Run Chrome browser without CORS](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)