# Why is my React app displaying an error at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following message when starting out my React app:

```
ERROR [object Object] at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56279:58) at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56302:7
```

Does anyone know what this means and how it can be resolved? If one disregards the error and proceeds onward, the app works just fine.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help with this

Comment: Have you looked at the budle.js file near the indicated line numbers?  The error doesn't say what kind of error, well an object error but thats it.

Comment: @easleyfixed I cannot find a bundle.js file anywhere in the app.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure the issue? I'm running into something similar

Answer (score 0):

It's a CORS error that is well described here [React: Axios Network Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980173/react-axios-network-error?rq=2)

In my particular case the solution was to add to `package.json`(the one from front-end ) a line:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", (before "dependencies")
```

and to write the path in :

```
const response = await axios.post(`/api/something/${ otherThing }/subdirector`,
```

instead of :

```
const response = 
     await axios.post(`http:localhost:8000/api/something/${ otherThing }/subdirector`,
```

Hope this will help

PS: Shaun Wassel says:

> "this is a common mistake for a beginner"