# Post Request net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm building React/Redux/Node app that incorporates Spotify's API with authorization code flow. It's a SPA with React-Router that has three routes: Login, Timeline, and Results. When traversing from Timeline to Results, I get this error:

```
POST http://localhost:3001/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[Here](https://github.com/samuelwstout/Classify) is the Github repo.

[Here](https://youtu.be/dSeZpvoTKuU) is a video of the error with Chrome DevTools open.

useAuth.jsx (custom hook)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const useAuth = (code) => {

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
   axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {
       code,
   }).then(res => {
       setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
       window.history.pushState({}, null, '/')
   }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
    })
 }, [code])

  return accessToken
}
export default useAuth
```

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const code = req.body.code
    const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
        redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    })

    spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(data => {
        res.json({
            accessToken: data.body.access_token,
            refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
            expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
        res.sendStatus(400)
    })
})

app.listen(3001)
```

App.js

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Login } from './Login'
import { Timeline } from './Timeline'
import { Results } from './Results'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'

const code = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code');

const App = () => {

  const [composers, setComposers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchComposers = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('composers.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      const listofComposers = data.composers.map((composer) => composer)
      setComposers(listofComposers);
    }
    fetchComposers();
  }, []);

  return (

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Login code={code} />} />
          <Route path='/timeline' element={<Timeline composerData={composers} />} />
          <Route path='/results' element={<Results code={code}  />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Results.jsx

```
export const Results = ({ code }) => {
  const accessToken = useAuth(code)
  console.log(accessToken)
```

**When I console.log(accessToken), it returns undefined.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Connection Refused means your app isn't listening on port 3001, on localhost.**
Chrome is trying to connect to it, but can't.

(A TCP SYN packet is sent and met with a TCP RST, but this is not relevant to your question)

try changing your `app.listen` to this and see what happens:

```
server.listen(3001, 'localhost'); // or server.listen(3001, '0.0.0.0'); for all interfaces
server.on('listening', function() {
    console.log('Express server started on port %s at %s', server.address().port, server.address().address);
});
```

also, a bit of a funny question:
are you sure you ran your app?
specifically the js file `server.js`...

because if it isn't running it most certainly can't be listening on any port, let alone 3001.

verify it's running **and** listening on the correct port using [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) or [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps) in powershell

Comment: You are most welcome! it happens to everyone at some point

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer helps to debug the error: [Unable to catch and log the Error response from an axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806333/unable-to-catch-and-log-the-error-response-from-an-axios-request/44806462#44806462)

> So essentially catch(error => ) is actually just catch(response => )

Try to `console.log(err.response.data)`

Comment: When I try `console.log(err.response.data)`, I get `useAuth.jsx:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at useAuth.jsx:19:1`